# Automorphism group of an R-module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, automorphism-group

Let R be a commutative ring.

It is well known that the automorphism group of the module $R^n$ is isomorphic to $GL_n(R)$. Is their a way to measure how much this fails for an arbitrary module M? Perhaps some short exact sequence involving $GL_n(R)$ and $Aut(M)$.

It feels like a natural question. I can imagine this failing without any conditions on M or R. But perhaps one of you knows something about this.

Comment: How would you be defining $\text{GL}_n(R)$ where $R$ is a ring? As the set of all $n \times n$ matrices such that the matrix with entries in R has an inverse? And then how would that act on an arbitrary module, $M$?

Comment: @JennyKenkel Oh yeah that does point at the "unnatural" side of the question